# How to pass currently logged in user to the model using generic views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am new to django and I was asked to associate currently logged in user with Context (my model class) the user creates.
How/where to retrieve the User (from `request.user`) object? How to set it in the model?
**Is it possible to pass `request.user` to view using generic views?**

Here is my Context class:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Context(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False)
```

Here is the form:

```
class ContextForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ContextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Context
        exclude = ('user')
```

URL from urls.py:

```
url(r'^create/$', CreateView.as_view(model=Context, form_class=ContextForm),name='context_create'),
```

Finally, context_form.html with crispy form

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces)! It has a [form mixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/forms.py) that pops the current user from the kwargs. There's also a [mixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views.py#L218-L228) for a class based view that passes the user to the form. 
If you're doing class based views, just use the mixins provided in forms.py and views.py, and override the save() method.

forms.py:

```
from braces.forms import UserKwargModelFormMixin

class ContextForm(UserKwargModelFormMixin, ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ContextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Context
        fields = ('title', 'description',)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        obj = super(ContextForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj
```

views.py

```
from braces.views import UserFormKwargsMixin

class CreateContextView(UserFormKwargsMixin, CreateView)

    model = Context
    form_class = ContextForm
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^create/$', CreateContextView.as_view(),name='context_create'),
```

You can also achieve it like this:

forms.py:

```
class ContextForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ContextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Context
        fields = ('title', 'description',)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        obj = super(ContextForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj
```

views.py

```
def some_view(request):
    ...
    form = ContextForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: But can user (request.user) be passed to general view in urls.py: url(r'^create/$', CreateView.as_view(model=Context, form_class=ContextForm),name='context_create')?

Comment: The current user would be passed on automatically from the view to the form. You're gonna have to define your class based view though, not use the generic one.

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify the new view, and the new urls.py

Answer (score 0):

In your model :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Context(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

in the view to associate with user:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContextForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email = form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
                    user.save()

                    obj = Context(user=user, title=form.cleaned_data['title'], description=form.cleaned_data['description'])
                    obj.save()
```

If you need to ask for login ,just add  **@login_required**

```
@login_required
def myfunction(request): 
     ...
```

and take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=45&cad=rja&ved=0CFQQFjAEOCg&url=http://hackedexistence.com/project-django.html&ei=CO4LUbrJC5Ko0AWopoCgCw&usg=AFQjCNG6NVaiY39iE2jhiFv1sQNoiqpO8A&sig2=LKU_2mQ2KsShLNT4_iUcLQ&bvm=bv.41867550,d.d2k)

**EDIT**

I've seen your edited question,You need to add this to your urls.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

This means that it will be passed to all templates that are rendered using a RequestContext, which all generic views are.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question

Comment: Yes, it didn't change anything (user is still not set up). But thanks for the tutorial, I will definitely look into it (esp. @login_required decorator).

Comment: Yes, correct. But I have this general view (CreateView.as_view(model=Context, form_class=ContextForm)) and I wonder if request.user can be passed there

Comment: override the form_valid method ,[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid)

Comment: Hmm, I added context processor to settings.py but it didn't help. I don't see any request object in **kwargs arguments that are passed. I think I need to define my class based view, not to use generic view...